# List GitLab push events

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i am trying to capture all the push events which were done today by using the command

`curl -X POST "http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/389/repository/tags?tag_name=${RELEASEVERSION}&private_token=*************"`

But i am not able to get GitLab Push events which were done today.

How can i print today's GitLab push events from command line?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a *Premium license* applied to the instance, you can enable [Repository Push Audit Events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html#repository-push) and then fetch the push events with [Audit Events API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/audit_events.html#instance-audit-events) when the data has been collected.

If, however, you are running a *free GitLab version*, you'll have to rely on logs and parse those instead.

The relevant logs on GitLab 13.5+ version are:

#### For pushes done in CLI over SSH

You will have traces of pushes in `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log` and in `/var/log/gitlab/gitaly/current`,

#### For pushes done over HTTP(S) protocol

Check `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current` and `/var/log/gitlab/gitaly/current`.

---

A single push event will have the same `correlation_id` in both logs.

The location of log files can be different if you have a source install. These locations are for standard Omnibus install.

Comment: bro, is there any way to get through gitlab api?

Answer (score 0):

For Ultimate GitLab instances only, you also have, with [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#streaming-audit-events-for-git-operations) (July 2022):

> ### Streaming audit events for Git operations
>
> You can now monitor the Git activity inside your groups with new audit events that are recorded when users push to or
> pull from repositories.
>
> This will include information such as the user name, the timestamp, and the project that was pulled from or pushed to.
>
> These events generate a high volume of data, so they are only available as
> [streaming audit events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_event_streaming.html).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_event_streaming.html#audit-event-streaming-on-git-operations) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/343984).

Answer (score 0):

You could view recent pushes by going to the Activity page in the GitLab UI. This does not seem to require a premium edition, since I do not have a premium edition but this works in our installation. Currently, this page offers a month of history. Example:

[image]

The URL I used was: https://[your GitLab host]/dashboard/activity.

One limitation to this is that it doesn't offer any filtering, like by branch or repository. It is possible to view only certain repositories on this tab: https://[your GitLab host]/dashboard/activity?filter=starred (shown in the image above) if you have "starred" your target repositories under your GitLab user.